# delete and get the sessionid in react and javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

I make an app in django and react and I want to check serverside if the user is still authenticated and if the user is not authenticated anymore I send 401 back to the client.

So I have some questions:

1. how I can check if there is sessionid in cookies? I tried `document.cookie` but it did not work
2. how to delete the sessionid??

Can someone help me please?

Comment: The sessionid cookie is protected, so JavaScript can not access that, it is thus set by the Django backend, and removed by the Django backend, or the browser, for example after quiting the browser, it can throw away these cookies.

Comment: Your backend is likely setting the session cookie as an HTTP-Only cookie, which means it's not accessible to JavaScript code running on your stie. This is probably a good thing! Let the backend tell your frontend whether the user is authenticated rather than your frontend somehow discovering that on its own.